# How to check if am I logged in to external app using java services?

Tags: java, javascript, php, web-services, web-applications

I have two separated web applications on two servers. One is PHP application, second is java application. From PHP applicaton I need to ask java app if "am I logged in to java app". I tried to use curl but It always return "false" - it makes sense, it doesn't know anything about session.

So I tried to use javascript/jQuery to send request and it always display message "couldn't connect to host". I found that `XMLHttpRequest()` doesn't work on cross platform.

When I'm using browser to ask service if "am I logged in to java app" I'm receiving correct response. But the problem is when I'm trying to do it the same from php app.

Comment: you'd have to transmit your client-side java app session ID/cookie to the php server, so it can include that id/cookie with its requests to the java server.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by 'XMLHttpRequest() doesn't work cross platform.' That is just a HTTP client side request from the browser, for both the PHP or Java web apps it makes no difference.

You have to understand a bit more how the 'am I logged in to java app' is actually working.
The Java App will typically send a cookie using the HTTP headers and the browser (for obvious security reasons) will not mix the session information from one web application to the other.

From what you are describing, what you are trying to achieve is referred to as Single Sign On (i.e. you log into one application and the rest will be able to make use of the same session). It requires a bit more work. You have to look at something like SAML.

I found this presentation on another answer here some time ago and bookmarked it, you might want to have a look at it. A bit old but still useful, then just look what ever is the latest and greatest tool for both PHP and Java.

http://www.slideshare.net/craigsdickson/fast-and-free-sso-a-survey-of-open-source-solutions-to-single-sign-on

This is a SAML API in PHP: http://simplesamlphp.org/

This is the replacement API for the old Sun OpenSSO: http://forgerock.com/products/open-identity-stack/openam/